# What is the function of this class?

Tags: java, arduino

What does "implements Runnable" mean?
I am sending data from arduino to this java file

```
public static class SerialReader implements Runnable {
    InputStream in;
    public SerialReader( InputStream in ) {
        this.in = in;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

Answer (score 3):

**implements** is a keyword in java for implementing an interface.

Acording to Oracle:

> The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose
>   instances are intended to be executed by a thread. The class must
>   define a method of no arguments called run.
>
> This interface is designed to provide a common protocol for objects
>   that wish to execute code while they are active. For example, Runnable
>   is implemented by class Thread. Being active simply means that a
>   thread has been started and has not yet been stopped.
>
> In addition, Runnable provides the means for a class to be active
>   while not subclassing Thread. A class that implements Runnable can run
>   without subclassing Thread by instantiating a Thread instance and
>   passing itself in as the target. In most cases, the Runnable interface
>   should be used if you are only planning to override the run() method
>   and no other Thread methods. This is important because classes should
>   not be subclassed unless the programmer intends on modifying or
>   enhancing the fundamental behavior of the class.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)

Comment: Is SerialReader a predefined class in java? because i did not see it to be defined in the code i have.

Comment: No SerialReader isn't a pre defined class in Java.

Comment: What is it then?

Answer (score 0):

implements is for implementing an interface.
and 
The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread.